# Numerical solution to the equation of curvature perturbation

Tags: cosmology, computational-physics, cosmological-inflation

[Numerical solution to Mukhanov-Sasaki equation](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/442907/)

In the above link, an equation is given which is the evolution equation of curvature perturbation as a function of $N$ (number of e-folds). In order to solve the above equation of curvature perturbation using Bunch Davies initial condition, we need to write the conformal time (tau) in terms of the number of e-folds $N$. Could you please help me how can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Conformal time $\tau$ is related to ordinary time $t$ as $dt=ad\tau$ ($a$ is time-dependent scale factor).
The e-fold number $N(t)$ can be defined as (using dot for the usual time-derivative)
\begin{equation}
\dot N=H\equiv \dot a/a~,
\end{equation}
where $H(t)$ is the Hubble function. Then we can write $N'(\tau)=\dot N(t)t'$, where prime is the derivative with respect to conformal time $\tau$. Since $t'=a$, we have $N'=aH$.

**From $t$ to $\tau$.** With this we can change the time variable of some function $f(t)$ from $t$ to $\tau$, so that the derivative $\dot f(t)$ can be written as
\begin{equation}
\dot f=\dot\tau f'=f'/a~,~~~{\rm because}~~\dot\tau=1/a~.
\end{equation}

**From $t$ to $N$.** To switch to $N$ as the time variable,
\begin{equation}
\dot f=\dot N f_N=Hf_N~,~~~{\rm because}~~\dot N=H~.
\end{equation}
Here $f_N\equiv df/dN$.

**From $\tau$ to $N$.** Finally when switching from $\tau$ to $N$,
\begin{equation}
f'=N' f_N=aHf_N~,~~~{\rm because}~~N'=aH~.
\end{equation}